# How to publish a npm module that can be auto import in WebStorm?

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, webstorm

I try to publish an easy module like follow:

the file list is:

```
|--[src]
|    |--[share]
|          |--share.moduel.ts
|          |--index.ts
|
|
|--package.json
|--index.ts
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "my-common",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.ts",
  "typings": "index.ts",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

index.ts

```
export { ShareModule } from './src/share/index';
```

src/share.module.ts

```
import {NgModule} from "@angular/core";
import {CommonModule} from "@angular/common";
import {FormsModule} from "@angular/forms";

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule
  ],
  declarations: [],
  exports: [CommonModule,FormsModule]
})
export class ShareModule { }
```

src/index.ts

```
export { ShareModule } from './share.module';
```

After I publish the npm module,and then `npm install my-common`, I try to press <kbd>Alt + Enter</kbd> on code 'ShareModule' in order to auto organize import statement, but it doesn't show the tab "***Add import statement***" which works like the Angular2 HttpModulem, FormModule, etc.

So how could I make my own module that can be auto import by key <kbd>Alt + Enter</kbd> in WebStorm like other Angular2's official module? Are there some key point I missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally,I find how to make it work.

Step 1
create two file in your `**/src/**` folder like follow:

index.d.ts
index.ts

Step 2
edit your index.d.ts
you show export the class you want to use <kbd>Alt + Enter</kbd> to import in WebStrom

for example

```
export declare class ShareModule {
}
```

Step 3
edit your index.ts like follow:

```
export {ShareModule} from './share/share.module';
```

Step 4
make two file in **/** folder like follow

index.ts:

```
export * from './src/index';
```

index.d.ts：

```
export * from './src/index'
```

Finally, the files should like follow:

```
    |--[src]
    |    |--[share]
    |    |      |--share.moduel.ts
    |    |--index.ts
    |    |--index.d.ts
    |
    |
    |--package.json
    |--index.ts
    |--index.d.ts
```

Now you can import your class by <kbd>Alt + Enter</kbd>